# ReactJS: How to host my single-page app in a different directory than root folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, hosting

I've already took a deep search on this topic but I haven't found anything useful with my case.

#### Issue

What I am trying to achieve is to successfully host my reactjs app on the hosting server I paid for. But when I use `npm run build` it clearly says that the app must be uploaded in the root directory of my website. Which is what I'm trying to overcome.

My hosting server details are:

- Apache version => 2.4.38
- PHP version => 7.0.33
- MySQL version => 10.0.38-MariaDB-cll-lve
- Architecture => x86_64
- OS => linux
- Shared IP Address => 67.XXX.XXX.XXX

  Perl access route => /usr/bin/perl

  Perl version => 5.16.3

  Kernel version => 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.19.9.el7.x86_64

I've tried to place it on a different directory and it just doesn't work...

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add something like this to your `package.json` file:

```
"homepage": "https://example.com/some/directory/app"
```